# Webapp that runs some local files

Tags: web-applications, vlc, firebreath, local-files

I'm developing some web app that controls some clients by web socket. At some point the server orders to clients to execute some video file, one of many, with ex. vlc... now i don't want to be dipendent to ie, so i am trying to solve this thinking in 2 ways, but still not really sure if i'm losing time and there is another much simple solutions.

the only solutions that i can find are:

- configure some simple plugin: trying with

> http://www.firebreath.org/ 
>   
>   that calls the player with some params like vlc --fullscreen, and runs it as a Process, while the browser calls the plugin and pass the video file name...
>   + use the vlc web interface, and call clients
>
> ```
> http://127.0.0.1:8080/
> ```

but still can't understand how can i pass the file name to play parameters

Comment: Can't you use the html5 video tag? Fallback to flash which 99% of browser has

Comment: You could do what you need with FireBreath, but you would need to be very careful with security considerations; if you decide to do this you might take some time looking at the FBTestPlugin example.

Comment: this doesn't really seem like a plugin is the correct fix, though

Answer (score 0):

Everything you are attempting to do sounds like a security risk. JS cannot be allowed to run programs on the client machine. The scope of JS execution is limited to its browser container.

Now you are trying to overcome this by creating a plugin, that could access installed programs and run them outside of the browsers secure container? This should not be possible.

> but still can't understand how can i pass the file name to play parameters

You can't. Or at least you should not be able to. If you wish to execute video files, use flash or some other related technology. I think the HTML5 videotag defaults to flash, but I'm not certain